# Why won't this JavaScript entity work? (specifically: property="&{JavaScript-statements};" )

Tags: javascript, html

I read on a book that "JavaScript entities are values from a script that you use in HTML."
I tried copying the code it showed me:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Entities Example</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--HIDE
function getWidth(){
  var w = eval(prompt("Enter image width:"))
  return w
}

function getHeight(){
  var h = eval(prompt("Enter image height:"))
  return h
}
//STOP HIDING-->
</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY>
<CENTER><IMG SRC="gun1.jpg" WIDTH="&{getWidth()};" HEIGHT="&{getHeight()};">
</CENTER></BODY></HTML>
```

**What is expected:**
This code is supposed to get the user's answer from a prompt and then return it to set the dimensions of an image.

**What resulted:**
When I ran the code, I did not get any prompt asking me for any dimensions.


I have already surfed through the web for an answer on this or at least on JavaScript entities but they only show how the code works and the syntax.

Comment: Pardon my asking, but just _how old_ is the book you're reading from? People stopped using `<UPPERCASE>` HTML tags in the late 1990s, and `<!--` _inside_ `<script>` elements was redundant by 1998...

Comment: The syntax for your attribute values is not native HTML, so it won't do anything. You might want to re-read your book to see if it talks about some other facility you need. Also, from the code you posted, you might want to look for a newer book. Web software books older then 3 or 4 years are suspect, older than 6 or 7 years probably simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript entities were a feature of Netscape Navigator 3.x that did not achieve widespread support.

You should read a book written this century.